# Read the text data separated by multichar delimiter and enclosed in single quotes into dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This is the sample data,

```
'id'|@|'name'|@|'sal'
'123'|@|'abvc'|@|'10000'
'234'|@|'dfgb'|@|'20000'
```

I need this data to be read into dataframe without single quotes

```
id   name  sal    
123  abvc  10000    
234  dfgb  20000
```

But i am getting the data in single quotes when reading through pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
 df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\test.txt",sep='\\|\@\\|',engine='python')

'id'    'name'    'sal'
'123'    'abvc'    '10000'
'234'    'dfgb'    '20000'
```

Can someone please help me

Comment: you can remove the quotes afterwards with `df['id'] = df['id'].str.replace("'", "")`

Comment: I have many columns, shouldn't there be simple option?

Comment: `df = df.replace("'","", regex=True)`? Or safer `df=df.apply(lambda x: x.str[1:-1])`.

Comment: @RichieV at that point you've lost the automatic type inference... so you'll be left with all objects... (instead of `id` and `sal` being number types - which I'm guessing is what's preferred)

Comment: @QuangHoang how about the headers?

Comment: Header would work the same: `df.columns = df.columns.str[1:-1]`.

Comment: its working !! I thought there would be some option to do this while reading data through pandas. But, this helped me too.

Comment: @Jennie do you want the results to just be strings... or did you want `id` and `val` for example to be numerics ?

Comment: @JonClements i dont want quotes in my dataframe.

Comment: @Jennie okay.. but using the approach suggested above... while it removes the quotes... you'll end up with the `id` and `val` columns being strings that just don't happen to have quotes, rather than being numbers

Comment: I think that shouldn't be a problem as after transformations i will be consuming everything as strings :-)

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is this:

```
dfw = pd.read_csv(r"c:/users/k_sego/weird.csv",sep="\|@\|")
dfw = dfw.replace(r"\'", '', regex=True)
df = dfw.rename(columns={"'id'": "id", "'name'": "name", "'sal'":"sal"})
```

which gives

```
    id  name    sal
0  123  abvc  10000
1  234  dfgb  20000
```